# ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables

Tags: sql-server, sas, sas-macro

This is the code itself - before enfolding the internal stuff into a macro, it all worked:

```
%macro test(product, dedi, pfi,md,sd,cIi,cIIi,cIIIi,cIo,cIIo,cIIIo,bm);
%let product = &Product;
<more let statements here for all variables>

<data pull happens here>

PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.ProdFilter AS 
SELECT t1.*
  FROM WORK.PRODCLAIMS2 t1
  WHERE t1.Product_Type = &Product
;QUIT;

<more code here> 
%mend

%test(&product, &dedi, &pfi,&Ded, &Sd,&CIib, &CIIib,&CIIIib, &CIob, &CIIob,&CIIIob,&bm);
```

It successfully is able to run the data pull, then breaks down when I first try to use a variable.  These are user defined variables using prompts, which seems to also work fine, but then I get the error:

"ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: DenP"

DenP is the user input, and I know it is a product.  It is not a column though - the column is t1.Product_Type, and I am trying to filter only to the rows with 'DenP' in that column.  This step works fine when not in a macro.

I am pretty sure it has to do with either how I have written and called the macro itself OR it could be that it's angry with how I named the prompts?  I included the first %let statement as an example - perhaps if I name the prompts differently this would make a difference?

We never get to  since it breaks with this first error.  Any guidance on where the problem is originating would be helpful - I thought I was supposed to list the variables in the macro ()  but perhaps I am supposed to list something else?

Comment: You need to show what the generated code looks like to be able to tell which macro variable is the one that is generating the code that has an error.  Turn on the MPRINT option and post the lines from the SAS log.

Comment: MLOGIC(TEST):  Parameter PRODUCT has value DenP

Comment: MLOGIC(TEST):  %LET (variable name is PRODUCT) MPRINT(TEST):   PROC SQL;
MPRINT(TEST):   CREATE TABLE WORK.ProdFilter AS SELECT t1.* FROM WORK.PRODCLAIMS2 t1 WHERE t1.Product_Type = DenPPOPSV ;
ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: DenP
NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
MPRINT(TEST):  QUIT;
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

Comment: Is this what you are asking about?  Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: It is perfectly fine to edit your question and add more information -- especially stuff that, as a comment, does not format well or is too long.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the value so SAS knows you are comparing to a string and not another column.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.ProdFilter AS 
SELECT t1.*
  FROM WORK.PRODCLAIMS2 t1
  WHERE t1.Product_Type = "&Product"
;QUIT;
```